# Natural frequency of robot arm

Tags: robotic-arm, design

I want to design a 3 DOF pick and place robotic arm. I've accomplished stress analysis. now i'm going to do frequency analysis. software give me natural frequencies in different configurations. but i don't know what to do about these frequencies in order to redesign robot. so i have some question in my mind.
What are vibration sources in robotic arm and what is appropriate natural frequency for robot?

Comment: I think the term appropriate natural frequency needs much more detail. There is probably no general "appropriate" natural frequency.

Comment: You know there is an operating frequency range based on excitation for robot. i think if we obtain it , appropriate natural frequency will be specified.

Comment: there are large robots, small robots, lightweight robots, robots which can lift up to two tons. There is no general appropriate frequency for robots. Also, there are many applications which are not affected by the natural frequency, since the application does not excite this frequency or the motion induced by exciting the natural frequency is negligible for the application.

Comment: thanks for answer ... could you explain about how designers calculate operating frequency range based on excitation and What are vibration sources in robotic arm?

Comment: everything that moves is a source of vibration for a robot. Motors, gearboxes in the joints, grippers, and some vibrations might even be payload related or external (e.g. train passing right next to your factory), even earthquakes might be relevant depending on the application. I am not sure what you mean by operating frequency range.

Comment: Every things you said like motors and gearboxes have the input excitation
frequency range. it's limited by motor speed. I wanna obtain these excitation
frequencies for robot and compare them to robot natural frequencies.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by input excitation frequency limited by motor speed and what do you mean by obtaining these frequencies to compare them.